# Random access in vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, random-access

While trying to randomly access an empty vector in c++, there is segmentation fault.

```
vector<int> g;
cout<<g[3];  //Segmentation fault
```

But if we do a single push_back() operation, then we can do random access there is no error:

```
vector<int> g;
g.push_back(1);
cout<<g[0]; //output = 1
cout<<g[3]; //output = 0
```

What is the reason behind this??

Comment: If i remember correctly, vectors allocate memory in chunks. You probably can't access a higher index. Regardless, this behavior is undefined

Comment: When first working with vectors (or even other containers) use `at` instead of `[]` at first.  `at` will catch when you go out of bounds and throw an exception.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Although, that's at some cost, which can be material especially when working through linear algebra calculations.

Comment: *But if we do a single push_back() operation, then we can do random access there is no error:* -- There is an error -- you chose an element that is outside the bounds of the vector.  What is the visible results of that error is a different story.

Comment: @Bathsheba True but when you first start learning about vector I would think safety should trump speed, at least until you get the hang of it.

Comment: You are accessing out of bounds. This is Undefined Behaviour. You broke the rules of the language and *any* result is possible. Don't do that.

Comment: Undefined behavior means only that the language definition does not tell you what the code should do. It does not mean that something bad will happen, although that's often the result.

Comment: @PeteBecker I categorise *silently continuing with garbage* as "something bad". **Much worse** than terminating unexpectedly

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour on attempting to acquire an element of a `std::vector` that's outside the *bounds* of that vector is *undefined*. **Don't** do it, and don't rely on any behaviour.

Perhaps your `push_back` causes `std::vector` to grab more memory than it needs as a guard against frequent reallocation and memory defragmentation?

Comment: I can see the case for not wanting defragmentation, but I think "against memory fragmentation" is a bit clearer.

Comment: Psychic debugging: Segmentation faults have a granularity of pages, and the `std::allocator<int>` allocated near (at?) the start of a page

Comment: Is a vector required to allocate space at all before you put something into it?

Comment: @cHao: No it isn't.

Comment: I might be wrong but i think vectors allocating more capacity than needed is to avoid frequent reallocations (lets say in a loop that uses `push_back`) rather than to avoid memory defragmentation. Or maybe you mean the same thing ;)

Comment: @user463035818: Yes, yours is a better way of putting it.